# jQuery DataTable - put data from the database into an input element

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery DataTable and I want to display some data into an input element rather than in an not editable row.

this is the jQuery DataTable initialization code:

```
var table = $('#monthly_table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        dom: "fr<'clear'>Ttip",
        ajax: '{{ url("reports/row-details-data") }}',
        tableTools: {
            sRowSelect: "os",
            sSwfPath: "../Content/DataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
            aButtons: [
                {
                    sExtends: "xls",
                    sButtonText: "Export to Excel",
                    sButtonClass: "save-collection btn-default"

                },
                {
                    sExtends: 'print',
                    sButtonText: "Print",
                    sButtonClass: "btn-default"
                }
            ]
        },
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'report_id'},
            {data: 'name', name: 'report_name'},
            {data: 'value', name: 'report_value'}
        ]
   });
```

At this point the data comes as an html normal table. I want those values to display in an input inside the table. just like the image shown below:

[image: DataTables example- Live DOM ordering]

All the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method, which I found in the jQuery Datatables documentation:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().data()

Example:
var cell = table.cell(4,1);
cell.data("VALUE").draw();

Don't forget to use .draw() to refresh the table.

UPDATE:
Or use table.cell(4,1).data(value).draw()

Comment: I guess you mean `table.cell(4,1).data(value).draw()` ?

Comment: it throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of undefined`

Comment: could you please show the code where are you using this

Comment: `return '<input name="code" class="form-control" type="text" value="'+ table.cell(meta.col, meta.row).data("{!! $code !!}").draw()+'" />'
          `